# MapKit MobileGestalt.c:1647: Could not retrieve region info

Tags: swift, mapkit, swiftui

I am using `MapKit` to show two annotations and distance between them. Everything works fine but I keep getting this error on the console. 
**MobileGestalt.c:1647: Could not retrieve region info**
Anybody knows what is causing it? Could it be some permission in the `.plist` file

Here is full console output:

`2019-11-10 00:21:41.419108+0100 Post DACH[20420:264466] Metal API Validation Enabled
2019-11-10 00:21:41.567416+0100 Post DACH[20420:264466] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:1647: Could not retrieve region info`

[image: Screenshot]

My code:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var requestLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var destinationLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    private let mapView = WrappableMapView()

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MKMapView {
        mapView.delegate = mapView
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) {
        let requestAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        requestAnnotation.coordinate = requestLocation
        requestAnnotation.title = "Package"
        uiView.addAnnotation(requestAnnotation)

        let destinationAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        destinationAnnotation.coordinate = destinationLocation
        destinationAnnotation.title = "Destiantion"
        uiView.addAnnotation(destinationAnnotation)

        let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: requestLocation)
        let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationLocation)

        let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
        directionRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
        directionRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)
        directionRequest.transportType = .automobile

        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)

        directions.calculate { (response, error) in
            guard let directionResponse = response else {
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                return
            }

            let route = directionResponse.routes[0]
            uiView.addOverlay(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)
            let rect: MKMapRect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect

            uiView.setVisibleMapRect(rect, edgePadding: .init(top: 50.0, left: 50.0, bottom: 50.0, right: 50.0), animated: true)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If "everything works fine" why not ignore the console messages and move on? (Especially if this message is simulator only.)

Comment: well im just worried if it could cause troubles later

Comment: Well come back when it does. We can't work on a problem that hasn't happened yet.

Comment: well it is a problem as you can see and it says: `Could not retrieve region info`

Comment: i am getting this same message but I am not getting the user location. Are you getting the user location? @RexhinHoxha

Comment: yes I do get the location

Comment: calculateResult closure is called in background task. Did you try to make your MKMapView updates in main queue?

Comment: @GerdCastan yes the problem still persists

Comment: I simply ran on device and didn't find anything in console log. Maybe got something to do with Simulator.

Answer (score 2):

You might have missed setting MKMapView delegate in your code.

Try setting `mapView.delegate = self` in your view where you have delegate methods implemented.

Comment: I have it here `    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MKMapView {
        mapView.delegate = mapView
        return mapView
    }`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue today. It appears that it's an issue with the simulator. Try running it in your device and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Go to Storyboard and then open the Structure Area.

Then you drag (with ctrl) the mapview exactly on the viewController symbol (round yellow symbol) and you choose delegate.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed the issue by adding `delegate`.

Comment: This answer can be improved by adding a concrete example and explaining how or why adding a delegate fixes the issue.